# Not able to add handler to Mac Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I want to add gmail to open mailto in Chrome.[image]

I have Version 22.0.1229.79 Chrome. When I try to add a hander, there is no button to add.

Where or How can I add a handler?

Answer (score 3):

Go to gmail in chrome and you should see a little icon in the omni-bar next to the "favorites star" Click on this and choose "Use Gmail". Now gmail will be in your protocol handler menu and will automatically handle the mailto: protocol.

I found all this information on google chrome's help site, http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1382847